# add a extra path to cpp -v

Tags: c++, ios, makefile, compiler-errors

I try to build with make and I get:

```
[ 50%] Building C object CMakeFiles/lws-minimal-http-server.dir/minimal-http-server.c.o
In file included from /Data/github/libwebsockets/minimal-examples/http-server/minimal-http-server/minimal-http-server.c:16:
/usr/local/include/libwebsockets.h:223:10: fatal error: 'openssl/ssl.h' file not found
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/lws-minimal-http-server.dir/minimal-http-server.c.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/lws-minimal-http-server.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

When I run `cpp -v` I get the following:

```
Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
 "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang" -cc1 -triple x86_64-apple-macosx10.12.0 -Wdeprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -E -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -discard-value-names -main-file-name - -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -mthread-model posix -mdisable-fp-elim -fno-strict-return -masm-verbose -munwind-tables -target-cpu penryn -target-linker-version 305 -v -dwarf-column-info -debugger-tuning=lldb -resource-dir /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/9.0.0 -I /usr/include -fdebug-compilation-dir /Data/github/libwebsockets/minimal-examples/http-server/minimal-http-server -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 204 -stack-protector 1 -fblocks -fobjc-runtime=macosx-10.12.0 -fencode-extended-block-signature -fmax-type-align=16 -fdiagnostics-show-option -fcolor-diagnostics -traditional-cpp -o - -x c -
clang -cc1 version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2) default target x86_64-apple-darwin16.7.0
ignoring duplicate directory "/usr/include"
  as it is a non-system directory that duplicates a system directory
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/local/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/9.0.0/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include
 /usr/include
 /System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
 /Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
End of search list.
```

In my `.bash_profile` I have:

`export OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR=/usr/local/opt/openssl/include
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include"
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin:$PATH"`

Comment: `CPPFLAGS` applies to C++. You are compiling C, so you should add the `-I` declaration to your `CFLAGS` as well. Alternatively, add the path to your `CPATH` or `C_INCLUDE_PATH` environment variable (sans `-I`).

Comment: @Botje According to [GNU Make and autotools conventions](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Variables.html), `CPPFLAGS` denotes C Preprocessor Flags and is the right place for `-I` options. C++
compilations flags are `CXXFLAGS`.

Comment: If you're using CMake to generate your makefiles then your question is a CMake question.  Simply setting common make variables like `CPPFLAGS` may not have any effect, unless your CMake files (`CMakeLists.txt`) are set up to accept those variables which hardly any do.  You should investigate the documentation of your software package for how to configure CMake to find OpenSSL, and/or modify the tags of this question to contain cmake.  This is not a compiler question or a makefile question: it's purely a CMake configuration question.